# slidify: prevent creation of git repo for presentation

Tags: r, rstudio, slidify

Slidify will auto-create a git repo for my presentation -- this happens since I configured git on RStudio.

Sometimes, this is useful, but mostly, I have my presentations as folders in my existing repos. This messes up the actual repo.

Is there a way to prevent slidify from creating a git repo? Some YAML config? I couldn't find any config toggle for this, any pointers would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is strange, but it seems the default must have changed at some point, even without `slidify()` getting an update. Anyway:

`author("presentation", use_git = FALSE)`

works.